# How to use lunadry?

Tags: lua, format, pretty-print

I'm trying to use Lua [Lunadry](https://github.com/batrick/lunadry) to reformat some really ugly code, but I'm getting this error everytime I try:

```
Formatting i,h
./lunadry: line 85: i,h: No such file or directory
```

I've tried argument I could think of, and I feel like I am missing something very simple :P

I read the README which says to use it by doing:

```
./lunadry --in-place file.lua
```

But again, every time I get the same error. Could someone tell me how to use this properly?

Comment: You get what error when you run `./lunadry --in-place file.lua`? Because that should work I think. The options are either `-i`/`-h` or `--in-place`/`--help`.

Comment: I just want to run it on a simple file in the same directory... './lunadry --in-place file.lua' is what I typed in (the file I want to reformat is actually called file.lua, just like it says in the README).

Comment: And what error are you getting from that? You can't be getting `./lunadry: line 85: i,h: No such file or directory` for that so if it isn't working what error are you getting?

Comment: This is exactly how I did it: http://pastebin.com/iNzyZb26

Comment: Huh. Interesting. Are you on OS X or a BSD? What does `getopt --test; echo $?` output?

Comment: I'm on OS X, and my output from that command is:

[19:38][boonie@dunhill-2][lunadry-master]$ getopt --test; echo $?
 --
0

Comment: I thought so. You have a non-GNU getopt binary which doesn't understand the options that script is using. You can install GNU getopt (from homebrew or something possibly) or rewrite the script to use the built-in getopts (which doesn't do long arguments unfortunately) or at the very least file an issue telling batrick to test getopt or rewrite to use getopts (or manual parsing).

Comment: Aha, well I'm glad that it wasn't just my stupidity that was why it wasn't working :P It was frustrating. But... I have no idea how to do what you just suggested. How do I install GNU getopt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lunadry expects GNU getopt behaviour.

OS X (and other BSD systems) have non-GNU getopt installed by default. This version of getopt is lacking many features and (at least historically) was fairly broken.

Available solutions are:

- install GNU getopt (possibly through [homebrew](http://brew.sh/) or similar system).
- rewrite script to use bash built-in `getopts` (will lose ability to parse --long-options)
- rewrite script to use manual option parsing (naively will lose ability to parse `-ih` but in this case that won't hurt much)
- file an issue asking batrick to do one of those rewrites

Comment: I installed homebrew and GNU getopt through it but I am still getting the same error... http://pastebin.com/AhgvCjTY

Comment: @JonathanMicaelPicazo Either it installed it as `gnu-getopt` in which case you need to alias it in your shell or edit the script to use that name or you just need to restart your shell (because your current shell believes it already knows what `getopt` means and isn't looking for the new binary).

Comment: I looked in the directory and the file is still called 'getopt'... I'm not sure how to alias or edit the script to do that... To restart the shell does it just require rebooting my laptop?

Comment: @JonathanMicaelPicazo Not even, just open a new terminal window.

Comment: Ah, okay! I did that and still no luck... I posted the issue on the github as well. No idea how to rewrite  the script to use the built-in getopts or use manual option parsing :/ Could you tell me how (if it isn't a bother)?

Comment: @JonathanMicaelPicazo Those are both somewhat substantial changes to the script unfortunately. What do you get if you run `type -a getopt` in your shell now? Do you still get `0` from `getopt --test; echo $?`?

Comment: @JonathanMicaelPicazo That `type -a` output says that you (or homebrew) added its path (I'm assuming `/opt/local/bin/getopt` is homebrew) after the default paths. You need it before the default paths to have its commands replace the others. Or use full paths. Edit the script on line 28 to say `/opt/local/bin/getopt` instead of just `getopt`.

Comment: Aha! Yay! That made some progress! But it got stuck on another error with missing LPEG... Brew doesn't install it and trying to install it manually just got more errors.

Comment: @JonathanMicaelPicazo You can submit a new question (probably on SuperUser or linux instead of on StackOverflow) for help getting that installed.